# Не срабатывает рекурсия

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Ожидается что при нажатии кнопки, блок будет двигаться в право, но ничего не происходит.
Помогите пожалуйста отловить ошибку. спасибо!

```js
let a = 0;

function move() {
  a = a + 5;
  document.querySelector(".test").style.left = a + "px";
  if (a > 200) {
    return true;
  }
  setTimeout(move, 500);
}

document.querySelector(".b-2").onclick = move;
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: chartreuse;
  
}
```

```html
  <button class="b-2">move</button>
  <div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: «Рекурсия» работает. Но без `position: relative` изменение left просто игнорируется. Но вообще не нужно такие тривиальные анимации делать на js. Используйте css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте `.test` позиционирование, например `position: absolute` для того чтобы срабатывало свойство `css left`